# How do I download a macOS beta point update?

Tags: macos, beta

What this question is not about

1. Downloading macOS Developer Beta Access Utility
2. Downloading a stable/GM release of macOS
3. Downloading the .0 release of a new macOS beta (when it is released at WWDC)

Say I want to install a macOS beta point update to a Mac that is never online (say if I had a lake house Mac or something). How would I download a .dmg or something so that I could install it on another machine. The macOS Developer Beta Access Utility just starts the update process on the machine it runs on.

Comment: Found this python script mentioned in this thread - https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2018/02/27/using-installinstallmacos-py-to-download-macos-high-sierra-installers/. This is the thread - https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/932rgz/downloading_osx_to_install_it_offline_later/.

Comment: There's this repo as well - https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts.

Comment: @slm Thanks. I haven't seen this before. Unfortunately the script doesn't currently give options for Mojave beta. This is what it outputs:  1    041-47723    10.14.4  18E2034  2019-03-25  macOS Mojave
 2    091-95155    10.13.6    17G66  2019-01-08  macOS High Sierra
 3    041-49229    10.14.4   18E226  2019-03-25  macOS Mojave

Comment: You probably have to change the `--catalogurl` to get at the betas.

Comment: @slm Ah, nice. I skimmed over that. After googling a bit though I don't know how to find the right CatalogURL...

Comment: Not finding it either ATM, might want to try this `softwareupdate --clear-catalog`.

Comment: If you're hitting a wall on that front I found this as an alt method - http://osxdaily.com/2017/09/27/download-complete-macos-high-sierra-installer/. It's for High Sierra but wonder if it could be adapted to Mojave?

Comment: Oh man what did you get us into, Greg the author maintains a lot of tools around updating macOS - https://github.com/wdas/reposado + his blog - https://managingosx.wordpress.com/.

Comment: These are the osxdaily directions for Mojave - http://osxdaily.com/2018/09/29/download-full-macos-mojave-installer/.

Comment: @slm Thanks, though it seems the osxdaily links are for not for the beta. I tried clear catalog too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, you're question is still a bit confusing to me, but I'll take a stab at it:

Your best bet is probably to comb through the listings you'll find in the Software Update catalogs found in Seeding.framework. That is:
`plutil -p /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Seeding.framework/Resources/SeedCatalogs.plist`, and (since we're talking Dev builds), probably
`curl -Ls https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.14seed-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog | plutil -p`.

You'll then need to grep around for the packages you're looking for; they're not always named the same, but if you grep for `macOSUpd`, you'll find the necessary packages, i.e., `http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/46/21/041-19988/kct9qwin7h5nz0awoc9ke03m2s7qp4q7t9/macOSUpd10.14.2ForSeed.pkg`.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, that does help. For some reason the utilities I was using wasn't able to create an installer from that file but searching through it does provide a beta combo update package file download link.